# prevent URL change on form submission using jquery submit() function

Tags: jquery

Hi I have written a jquery code where I am submitting the form using jquery submit() function on click of button . **But as the form is submitting Url is getting changed I don't want my url to be changed**, I dont want to use ajax as well because I need to refresh the page to get the latest data in a row after submission.

Below is the snippet of code and image attached for the url

```
$("#itemupdateModelForm").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        return false;
    });

    $(".itemupdateButton").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        var form = $('#itemupdateModelForm');
        var url = form.attr('action');
        var newUrl = url + currentRowItemId;
        form.attr('action',newUrl);
        $( "#itemupdateModelForm" ).submit();
        return false;
    });
```

[image]

After submission of form

[image]

I want my url to be unchanged after submission of form without ajax
Below is the model form

```
<div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-7">
<div class="itemUpdateTaskForm">
   <form th:action="@{/category/{id}/item/(id=${categoryId})}" th:method="post" th:object=${updateItemModel} id="itemupdateModelForm">               
        <div class="modal fade" id="updateTaskModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel" th:text="${categoryName}">Edit</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="title">Current Stock Quantity:</label>
                            <input th:field="*{currentStockQuantity}" value="" type="text" class="form-control" id="crntstckqnty" name="currentstockquantity" placeholder="currentstockquantity" readonly="readonly"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="title">Item Price:</label>
                            <input th:field="*{currentPurchasePrice}" value="" type="text" class="form-control" id="current_item_price" name="current_item_price" placeholder="Current Item Price" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="status">Unit:</label>
                            <select id="unit" class="form-control" name="unit" th:field=*{unit}>
                                <option th:each="status : ${T(com.inventory.domain.ItemWeightUnit).values()}"
                                        th:text="${status}" th:value="${status}">
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="title">Take Item:</label>
                            <input th:field="*{updatedQuantity}" value="" type="text" class="form-control" id="updatedQuantity" name="updatedQuantity" placeholder="updateQuantity"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary itemupdateButton" value="save"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to update record in current page?

Comment: @Siddharth Yes I want to update in current page basically there is page containing row on click of row I am opening a model and submitting data to backend and from backend I am returning the same page containing row

Comment: action define the url which will be redirect when you submit the form whether you put submit button or you submit from jquery, it will be redirect until you use ajax form submit. To achieve your requirement, you should redirect to the referrer url when the form submission is success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reload your page after record update successfully, like below i use javascript for it.

```js
window.location.reload(true);
```

[here is reference link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use AJAX, then a GET/POST request need to be done.

The easiest way would be to have a redirect to the original page from the page receiving the form data.

That is, once `/category/1/item/9` has processed the form data, redirect to `/categ/Masala`. This way the refresh you desire to have the latest data will be done too.

Another way is to process the data in the same URL than the form is, but with different method (POST instead of GET), or rely in a logic like *if post data is available process it, if not, display the form*, but you still would need to *redirect* or render the page anyways.

Comment: you could post to the same page with the row info in the body of the request, too... but you'll always have to deal with the consequences of the call